# How should I center these list items at the bottom of my page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am having trouble thinking of the best way to make my list items centered along the bottom of the page.

I am running bootstrap 3 btw.

Here is a link to the page:

```
http://69.50.196.73/projects/peap/index.php
```

As you can see on the bottom the 4 list items on the bottom:

```
<!-- Bottom Navagation Menu -->
<div class="col-lg-12 bottom-nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>more about peap</li>
            <li>meet the team</li>
            <li>faq</li>
            <li>press release</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that bootstrap CSS apply `float:left` to navigation list items.

You can try to override it with your own CSS and apply following styles to `<li>`:

```
float:none;
display: inline-block;
```

And then apply `text-align` to container:

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: Or you could do margin: 0 auto; instead of text-align. Whatever floats your boat.